# Using SQL server compact as user identity database in a self-hostet asp.net web api service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, owin, asp.net-identity-2, azure-service-fabric

I have a self hostet asp.net web api service running on Azure Service Fabric. To store user accounts I wanted to use SQL server compact.

I created an empty test.sdf database and added the database to the App_Data folder. Then I added all requiered nuget packages and the connection string in App.config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|test.sdf; Persist Security Info=false;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

In startup.cs I run this config code:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(AuthDBContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManagerModel>(UserManagerModel.Create);
```

The AuthDBContext class looks like this:

```
public class AuthDBContext : IdentityDbContext<UserModel>
    {
        public AuthDBContext()
            : base("AuthDBConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }

        public static AuthDBContext Create()
        {
            return new AuthDBContext();
        }
    }
```

I tried to debug the AuthDBContext class, but the debugger don't step in to this code `app.CreatePerOwinContext(AuthDBContext.Create);`.

And after running the code (without exceptions) the database is still empty. How can I see if the database is correctly connected? How can I fill the database with the statndard entity identity framework tables?

Is that even a good practice with SQL server compact database?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for my project I don't use SQL databases anymore. I found a solution to use Azure Table Storage as identity storage provider.

https://identityazuretable.codeplex.com/

That works really great.